# Presentation on WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I have just start to learn wpf. Can anybody clear me the following to give a presentation on WPF.

1. What is WPF?
2. Why we need it.
3. Difference b/w Win form and wpf.
4. windowsform vs WPF.

Geetha.

Comment: seriously, use google for ALL of these questions, you will get better results

Comment: Scatter-shot... i think buying a WPF book would be a better bet since it'd touch all of those topics... difficult to answer that comprehensively in a SO post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check these posts/articles -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx

http://www.wpftutorial.net/Home.html

This site is totally dedicated to WPF, you can find a lot of information there -

http://www.wpfwiki.com/

If you are coming from WinForms background these links will also be helpful -

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/llobo/migrating-winforms-to-wpf-links-to-info)

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/from-winform-to-wpf-a-quick-reference-guide/?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=email-reflector&utm_content=Winforms_to_WPF-20100329&utm_campaign=.NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165605.aspx

And as Mark said, use Google for best results :)

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you what it's like to use WPF instead of WinForms, if you like.

- Easy to make clean separation between code and presentation.
- Easy to reuse styles, elements, etc.
- Microsoft UI Automation! And it works.
- Xaml binding is dynamic!
- Data templates rock.
- Pretty, pretty. I have yet to try Expression Blend.
- Prism shell makes dynamically loading modules easy.
- It feels more like writing a web page than writing a windows app.

I'm not a massive MS fan, but I do like WPF. Much more lovely than Swing or WinForms, anyway.

I made a little pet shop example on this open-source project here:

http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/

Browse the code at:

http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/#hg/Example.PetShop

Enjoy!